# Function "ST_WITHIN" not found in Spring Boot Application using h2 In-Memory Database and Hibernate Spatial

Tags: spring-boot, h2, geospatial, spatial, hibernate-spatial

In a Spring Boot application (h2 in-memory database + Hibernate Spatial) in a Junit test, I'm getting error "Function "ST_WITHIN" not found" for a "within" query

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

test/resources/application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=va
spring.jpa.database=h2  
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.h2geodb.GeoDBDialect
```

LocationRepository.java

```
@Query(value = "select l from Location l where within(l.position, :box) = true")
List<Location> findByPositionWithin(@Param("box") org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry box);
```

LocationEntity.java

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "GEOMETRY")
private org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point position;
```

Obviously, the alias ST_WITHIN is missing. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Spatial functions for H2 are added by https://github.com/jdeolive/geodb.

Comment: H2 doesn't provide own spatial functions, there is an H2GIS extension for them and also some smaller projects. Hibernate Spatial uses GeoDB for a some weird reason, but GeoDB is basically unmaintaned and should be used with archaic versions of H2 without built-in `GEOMETRY` data type. You can try to use H2GIS with Hibernate Spatial instead with the same `GeoDBDialect`. Compatible versions of H2 and H2GIS need to be used, and H2GIS needs to be initialized with `CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS H2GIS_SPATIAL FOR "org.h2gis.functions.factory.H2GISFunctions.load";
CALL H2GIS_SPATIAL();`.